# Python and Shell commands issue

Tags: python, apache, shell

currently I'm developing a small project in which i'd like to execute some shell commands from a local webserver using Apache and Python.

I'd like to execute this command (shows the ip's of the devices connected to the server) and assing its output to a variable in Python:

```
grep -o '^[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' access.log
```

When i type this in the terminal, it shows the Ip's correctly. But i want to execute this command inside a python script which looks like this:

```
import os

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Connected devices</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Conected Devices</h2>'
f = os.popen("grep -o '^[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' access.log")
now = f.read()
print now

print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

When i call the python script from my server i can only see the title (Connected devices). Do you know which could be my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you show your access.log file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check in which directory the script is being run.

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

If its running on correct directory, try with below :

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

cmd = "grep -o '^[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' access.log"
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
output = p.stdout.read()
print output
```

Comment: If I use your code it says "not such file or directory". I tried adding the whole path, then it says "permission denied". Then I tried to add sudo and it says "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Comment: Ok, so path and permission seems to be the issue. How and where are you executing the script ? Is it under the same user under which access.log is present or some different user?

Comment: The python script is in the /usr/lib/cgi-bin directory. It's called from a .cgi file. That part works fine because I can see the header of the python script in the webserver. I added the script to the group www-data which is the same than Apache. Maybe if I copied the file to /usr/lib/cgi-bin directory and then tried to grep could be a solution?

Comment: 2 options to check out. 1) try your grep command from /usr/lib/cgi-bin direstory (with full path to the access.log file). ## 2) Change the PWD inside python script to the path where access.log is present.

Comment: Also, as said before, try to print getcwd() from python script and try to run the grep command from there, any permission issue can be validated this way

Comment: hmm..and what about output of getcwd() ?

Comment: Grep from inside the cgi-bin folder works fine. If I print getcwd() it shows the current path which is fine but i don't understand how to grep from here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46746/discussion-between-arunmu-and-aldridge1991)